# Cannot find path specified when trying to add existing embedded resource in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: path, visual-studio-2022, embedded-resource, solution-explorer

I have a C# Solution in Visual studio where one of the projects is the UI version of the software and the other project is the commandline version.  Both versions require some xml definitions.  I've added an embedded xml to the UI version but when I go to add the file to the commandline version, it throws an error saying it can't find the path specified.

[image]

The Solution explorer looks like . . .

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to add the hg5700.xml to the other project.

The file does exist as I've added it to the UI project.

I'm not that savvy with the various Visual Studio icons.  Does the open folder vs the closed folder give any clue?  How about the different icons on the embedded files?  I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: The padlock symbol denotes its been checked in to source control.  I _think_ the arrow icon that's on the one `i300a.xml` icon denotes its a shortcut.  The `</>` looking symbol just denotes that its an XML file.  I'm unsure what the open folder icon means.  Presumably its open... but I can't reproduce that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going on here.  The other project added the xml files as a link.  You have to go into add -> Existing Item . . .

[image]

[image]

I never realized there was a dropdown to add as a link.